moments of limitless destiny?

And there in the dark among glowing fragrant cigarettes, watching the laborious approach of that low twisted figure with helplessly tossing legs, he felt moments of limitless destiny.

(From Fat City by Leonard Gardner.)
Does this phrase mean "at that moment he felt what was happening seemed to occur forever."

Please give the source of this quotation. Without context it's impossible to say what it means.

@KateBunting Leaving the arena past the lame and blind still moaning and chanting outside the doors, Lucero was followed by a group of admirers. Sometimes as many as twenty, they accompanied him up the unlit street, ingratiating, shouting, waiting with him at each corner for the last of the group to catch up—a smiling young cripple who dragged himself along the pavement on a piece of rubber tire. And there in the dark among glowing fragrant cigarettes, watching the laborious approach of that low twisted figure with helplessly tossing legs, he felt moments of limitless destiny.

@KateBunting it is an excerpt from the novel Fat City.

@KateBunting here the narrator tell us about a Mexican boxer and his bouts in the ring. This person has grown in poverty and fights to make ends meet.

Your destiny is what is going to happen to you in the future. I guess that having so many admirers made him sometimes feel that there were no limits to what he would be able to achieve.

Compare: the destiny of the narrator and the destiny of the cripple. That's the point. The point is that his is limitless as opposed to the cripple, who has little to look forward to. I don't understand why you chose the answer you chose...

@Lambie my problem was with the meaning of the destiny here, and i also had the same thoughts, but i wasn't sure . And in the other answer, the destiny was explained as I expected.

the word destiny is in the dictionary. The point is the contrast.

To "feel limitless destiny" is to have a sense of the many things that are yet to come in the future. Destiny refers to a sense of fate, the notion that events in the world are on a fixed path which will come to happen. A sense of limitless destiny refers to the many forms this might take, the unknowable direction of unlimited possibility. Here, "moments" refers to the time period in which the feeling is felt, for only short glimpses.
The passage indicates that as the person approaches, the narrator has ephemeral feelings of unlimited possibility about the future which he is destined to fulfill.

Meaning: [...]he felt moments of limitless destiny.
Destiny is what is waiting for you in the future.
Destiny can be qualified by all sorts of adjectives.

happy, sad, wonderful, etc.

Here, it is limitless, meaning it has no boundaries or limits, all sorts of things can happen. This is in contrast to poor cripple whose destiny is very limited, limited to dragging himself along the pavement on a tire.
